# Set access permission just to particular user

Tags: c#, security, network-programming

I have a shared folder in my local network. now i want to deny everyone to access to it and just allow to a particular user. I used `DirectoryInfo` and `DirectorySecurity` classes but i could only deny everyone and when that particular user wants to access to this folder recieve "Access to this path is denied" message.
Please help me.

Comment: this doesn't sound like a programming problem

Answer (score 0):

[How to programmatically set NTFS file system folder permissions by using Active Directory Service Interfaces in Microsoft Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899553/en-us?fr=1)